# Large table issue in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have large tables with about 2.2 gbs of data. When I use SELECT * to select a row in the tables, it takes about 14 mins to run. Is there a method to speed up this query?

Here are some other information that might be helpful:

- ~ 2 million rows
- ~ 25k columns
- data type: Varcar
- Warehouse:
  Size: Computer_WH
  Clusters: min:1, max:2
  Auto Suspension: 10 minutes
  Owner: ACCOUNTADMIN

Comment: I assume you are not just running “SELECT * FROM TABLE” as that’s not selecting a single row - please update your question with the actual SQL and also the EXPLAIN PLAN when you run it. BTW 2 million rows/2.2Gb is not a large table

Comment: When you say 2.2 gbs, do you mean the size or the number of rows? Because it looks very small to me for a table with 2 M rows and 25K varchar columns.

Comment: What is a reason for such query? Do you want to display results in the Snowflake gui, or redirect it to some file? Maybe not select is a problem, but a javascript trying to draw 25k columns... We need more details from you.

Answer (score 4):

2gb is not that large, and very much should not be taking 14m on a X-SMALL warehouse.

First rule of Snowflake, don't `SELECT * FROM x`, for two reasons,

- The query compile has to wait for all meta data to be loaded for all partitions, before the plan can start being built as some partitions might have more data that the first partitions. Thus the output shape cannot be planned until all is known.
- Second reason, when you "select all columns", all columns are loaded from disk, and if your data is unstructured JSON is has to rebuild all that data, which is "relatively expensive". You should name the columns you want, and only the columns you want.

If you are wanting to join to another table to do some filtering, just select the columns needed to do the filter, and the join, and then get the set of keys you want and re-join to the base table on those results (sometimes as a second query) so pruning can happen.

sigh, I have just looked at your stats a little hard 25K columns... sigh. This is not a database, this is something very painful..

As a strong opinion you cannot have a row of data that makes sense to have 25K related and meaning full columns. You have a table with a primary key, and it should have something like 25K rows of subtype data per attribute. Yes it means  you have to exploded the data out via a PIVOT or the likes, but it's more honest about the relations present in the data, and how to process this volume of data.

Answer (score 0):

With columnar databases each column in a table has it's own file. Previously each table was a file (older DBMS's).   If you have 25,000 columns you'd be selecting 25,000 files.

Some of these files are big and some are small -> this is dependent on the data type and # distinct values.

If you found a column that say had 100 distinct values and just selected that column from your table I'd guess you'd get sub second response times.

So back to your problem ... instead of choosing all the columns (*) why not just choose some interesting ones?